# Printing list as table (row, col)

Tags: python, list

**I'm trying to print a list as a table**

The following code creates specified amount of rows and columns (in other words, it creates a list of a specified size).

```
finalgrid1 =[[0 for j in range(keyword_size)]  #print rows (size of keyword)
             for i in range(1 + new_grid_size)] #print column (size of ciphers)
print(finalgrid1)
```

The result printed is (when keyword_size = 3):

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Could someone show me how to print it in the following format.

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I'm working on creating a Cipher encoder and decoder program as part of an assignment. 
I've implemented the majority of it already - just stuck with printing it in the right format (as a table).
Btw, I am not asking you to apply any changes whatsoever, I only want to know how to print the list in the format of a table, that's all.

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, essentially prints each list out until there are none left to print

```
i = 0
while i < len(finalgrid1):
    print finalgrid1[i]
    i += 1
```

Comment: Worked perfect. I'll accept your answer. After 4 minutes :p

Comment: @kukac.. I don't see what's more simpler than that.

Comment: There is a slightly more elegant solution. `for row in finalgrind1: print row`

Comment: haha that worked too. shame i can't accept a comment as an answer :p

Comment: No worries :) The original answer does the same thing, my solution is just more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Stringify each list and join them together:

```
>>> grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>>
>>> print('\n'.join(str(x) for x in grid))
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```